# Finding replacement battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, replacement

I would like to revive an older gadget (GT-100 GPS tracker) that is still functional but has a dead battery. However, I am unable to find detail about proper battery type.

The original battery says only LSSP042532AU / 7A22 / 07575.

[image: Battery photo]

From these data I have found (at https://www.ancoo-battery.com/en/new/LS.html) its capacity (250 mAh) and type (Li-Ion), but not voltage.

Of course, the voltage probably is 3.6 V - 3.8 V or 4.2 V, but how to find? They are not interchangeable... what do the letters and numbers on the battery mean?

Comment: *Of course, the voltage probably is 3.6V - 3.8V or 4.2V, but how to find?...They are not interchangeable* They are! I do not think you realize that 3.6 to 4.2 V is the standard voltage range of these type of Li-Ion pouch cells? At 3.6 V it will be almost discharged. At 4.2 V it is fully charged. So there is no need to worry about 3.6 V, 3.8 V or 4.2 V. Any Li-Ion cell of the same size will do the job.

Comment: This is a single lithium pouch cell; they are typically identified by their size in millimetres; this one may be 4x25x33mm but satisfy yourself if that.  It you can’t get one with an identical connector then you can splice the old connector on to the new cell.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please note that questions on repair of devices are considered as off-topice. Also asking for purchasing recommendations is off-topic. Those questions are in most cases very specific to a device or a component. The question and its answers don't yield any benefit for the community.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie However, note that lithium iron phosphate (LiFePO₄) cells are *not* interchangeable with other lithium-ion cells, as they require slightly different considerations for charging! That said, I've never seen a LiFePO₄ cell in that pouch format, so you should be fine.